# Dataframe reading problems

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I have a DataFrame generated by the following block:

```
url <- "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
adult <- read.csv(url ,strip.white = TRUE ,header = FALSE )
colnames( adult ) <- c("age"," workclass "," final weight ","education "," education -num"," martial - status ","
                    occupation "," relationship "," race ","sex"," capital-gain "," capital - loss ","hours -per - week ","native -
                    country ","income")
```

The values in the "income" column are either "<=50k" or ">50k". when I try to select the people with income ">50k", I use the following comand:

```
richs = adult[adult["income"] == ">50k",]
```

however, the richs DataFrame is always empty. What am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: You need `adult[adult[["income"]] == ">50k",]`  The reason is that `adult['income']` is still a data.frame with one column.  By comparing with `==`, you get a matrix of 1 column.  Instead you need to extrac the column as a vector by using `[[`.  Also, it is a `factor`, so convert to `character`

Comment: i.e. `adult[as.character(adult[["income"]]) == ">50K",]`

Comment: it's `>50K` instead of `>50k`

Comment: @Stephan is rigth, also you can use dplyr: adult %>% dplyr::filter(income == '>50K')

Answer (score 0):

First, I will download the data into a data frame with strings as factors:

```
>adults <- read.csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data', header = FALSE)
> str(adults)
'data.frame':   32561 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ V1 : int  39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 9 levels " ?"," Federal-gov",..: 8 7 5 5 5 5 5 7 5 5 ...
 $ V3 : int  77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
 $ V4 : Factor w/ 16 levels " 10th"," 11th",..: 10 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 ...
 $ V5 : int  13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
 $ V6 : Factor w/ 7 levels " Divorced"," Married-AF-spouse",..: 5 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 ...
 $ V7 : Factor w/ 15 levels " ?"," Adm-clerical",..: 2 5 7 7 11 5 9 5 11 5 ...
 $ V8 : Factor w/ 6 levels " Husband"," Not-in-family",..: 2 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ V9 : Factor w/ 5 levels " Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 ...
 $ V10: Factor w/ 2 levels " Female"," Male": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ V11: int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
 $ V12: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V13: int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
 $ V14: Factor w/ 42 levels " ?"," Cambodia",..: 40 40 40 40 6 40 24 40 40 40 ...
 $ V15: Factor w/ 2 levels " <=50K"," >50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
```

If you look at the data close, you will notice that the feature you are working on is a factor having two classes: 1 = "<=50K" and 2 = ">50K". One fast way to extract the samples with class 2 of this feature is to convert it to integer and perform the operation on it:

```
> richadults = adults[as.integer(adults$V15) == 2, ]
> str(richadults)
'data.frame':   7841 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ V1 : int  52 31 42 37 30 40 43 40 56 54 ...
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 9 levels " ?"," Federal-gov",..: 7 5 5 5 8 5 7 5 3 1 ...
 $ V3 : int  209642 45781 159449 280464 141297 121772 292175 193524 216851 180211 ...
 $ V4 : Factor w/ 16 levels " 10th"," 11th",..: 12 13 10 16 10 9 13 11 10 16 ...
 $ V5 : int  9 14 13 10 13 11 14 16 13 10 ...
 $ V6 : Factor w/ 7 levels " Divorced"," Married-AF-spouse",..: 3 5 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 ...
 $ V7 : Factor w/ 15 levels " ?"," Adm-clerical",..: 5 11 5 5 11 4 5 11 14 1 ...
 $ V8 : Factor w/ 6 levels " Husband"," Not-in-family",..: 1 2 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 ...
 $ V9 : Factor w/ 5 levels " Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 2 2 5 5 5 2 ...
 $ V10: Factor w/ 2 levels " Female"," Male": 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ V11: int  0 14084 5178 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V12: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V13: int  45 50 40 80 40 40 45 60 40 60 ...
 $ V14: Factor w/ 42 levels " ?"," Cambodia",..: 40 40 40 40 20 1 40 40 40 36 ...
 $ V15: Factor w/ 2 levels " <=50K"," >50K": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

In the new data frame (richadults) you will have 7 841 samples only with those individuals that have their income >50K. The original data set has 32 561 samples.